# Referencing static library in VC++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am trying to statically link [this](https://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/) library into my VS C++ project.First I compiled the source as a static lib.Linked it via VS Project properties.The .exe project works fine.Then I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) MS manual on how to compile the static lib into the executable and following the steps outlined there now if I am running the executable I am getting these errors:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBlendFunc@8
referenced in function _text_buffer_render  E:\Documents\visual studio
2012\Projects\XXXXEngine\FreeTypeTest\text-buffer.obj

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBindTexture@8
referenced in function _text_buffer_render  E:\Documents\visual studio
2012\Projects\XXXXEngine\FreeTypeTest\text-buffer.obj
```

To me it seems like GLEW.lib errors.Does it mean I have to link also glew.lib statically as the freetype GL depends on it ?
Also, can I just use the lib with the executable without adding it to references, or it won't work in release build?I am asking it as I am quite confused with how the static linking should be done.I mean,now the executable works without adding the library to the project reference.Then why can't it be used just like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me it seems like GLEW.lib errors

They are not, glBindTexture() is an OpenGL function.  The MSDN library page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Scroll to the bottom, it shows you the .h file that declares it (you already that right since the compiler didn't complain) and the .lib you need to link.

Right-click your project, Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies setting.  Add opengl32.lib.  Or to use the upvoted answer's suggestion, you can inject the linker directive in your source code:

```
#include <gl\gl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
```

Comment: gl functions are exposed via GLEW extension loader afaik but I do see I have forgot to link opengl32.lib...

Comment: No idea what "extension loader" is supposed to mean.  GLEW is not available on Windows, you'd have to find it elsewhere.  It isn't very useful, just some helper functions to get the spinning cube demo going.

Comment: That's fine, I do know what is GLEW and how to use it ;) I just  forgot I needed opengl32.lib  too.Thanks.It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pragma mark your library?
Like so:
`#pragma comment(lib, "any.lib");`

Comment: What will it do?Will it compile the lib into executable?